# can i store an sql query full of CTEs as a variable in python and use that variable to join with another query

Tags: python, sql, pandas, automation

i am trying to automate some SQL reports and trying to replicate the query in python.

I want to store my sql query (full of CTEs) in a simple variable lets say 'query_report'.

I then want to use 'query_report' in another sql query to join the two queries together.

Is what i am asking even possible?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, it would help if you provide the community with a starting point of what you have tried. if you have not tried anything yet, please do that first :). also, provide a minimal reproducable example: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.